# disposing object context on application_endrequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm facing an issue with the EF4 object context which I store inside *HttpContext.Current.Items*, and then want to dispose as soon as the request is handled fully.

On Aplication_EndRequest event I call the Terminate() method of the RepositoryContext, which would find the active *ObjectContext* from the *HttpContext.Current.Items* collection, and call *Close()* on its connection and *Dispose()* on it.

The problem is that sometimes I get weird behavior on one of my pages. On some occasions I get an error saying:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection

I thought that maybe this might happen since not only page requests call the Application_EndRequest event once they finish but also image requests and etc', and hence maybe sometimes other requests disposes the main page request ObjectContext before it is finished doing its job, but that should not happen since everything is made on the collection *HttpContext.Current.Items* which is of course not shared between HTTP requests.

Also, from research maybe it is caused due to lazy loading of some db requests, but this should not be the case here because I do not call Dispose anywhere else on code (I've checked) and hence Dispose() on the EndRequest should be called only when **everything** is finished, shouldn't it?

Any ideas on what might cause this? How can I test it? what would you suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the stack trace look like when you get this error?

Comment: Can you post the code of your RepositoryContext class ?

Comment: here is the trace:
http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/3210/erroryourate.jpg

it seems that it is because in the middle of operation the object context is being disposed. But I still don't get how that can happen, if I only dispose on Application_EndRequest.

Comment: it seems like this only happens in static extension methods, when I try to access a navigational property of some entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that Dispose() was already called on the ObjectContext. There are many different reasons as to why this is happening, but it boils down to the fact that something is calling Dispose() before Application_EndRequest. Without all of the source it would be impossible to tell exactly why.

Because you are asking for recommendations, my first would be to take the ObjectContext out of HttpContext. The database connection should only live for a short time, and execute a specific task. If it is short lived you can put the ObjectContext inside of a using statement which will automatically call Dispose() for you.

Comment: I think the time of a request is ok. This pattern is inherited from NHibernate and it's called open-session-in-view. It works fine.

Comment: There is nothing stopping doing open session-in-view without putting the ObjectContext in the HttpContext. The ViewModel would know how to perform the actions to hit the database at the time the View is being rendered.

Having a per request context also means that it is not intuitive on what SaveChanges() would actually perform, as the entire requests life would need to reviewed.

Comment: Well, I've checked and checked and no dispose from anywhere else, I've searched all "using" and all "dispose" on source code on all solution, and nothing.
For now, I'm just doing objectContext.Connection.Close() instead of dispose and that seems to work ok.
BTW, this only happens on navigation properties and not anything else.

Comment: @sagi did you ever find another solution?  i'm seeing the same issue you describe.  Nothing else is disposing the context early. I can repro it every time using an objectdatasource pointed at a repository method that returns a lazy-loaded IQueryable result set. my objectdatasource gets the objectcontext from httpcontext in the onobjectcreating event.  works fine if i return non-lazy-loaded(List) or create objectcontexts as needed (instead of keeping it in httpcontext).  driving me crazy...

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have a class that provides you the current ObjectContext, it's possible a programmer, following some examples from a blog or something like that, had written this:

```
using(var context = ContextProvider.GetCurrentContext()){
    ...
}
```

and disposed the ObjectContext before the request ends.

If you want to test where the ObjectContext is being disposed, you can do this:

In your ObjectContext implementation, change the Dispose method to:

```
public override void Dispose() {
    throw new InvalidOpearationException("Gotcha!");
}

public void ActuallyDisposePlease() {
    base.Dispose();
}
```

And in the Application_EndRequest call the ActuallyDisposePlease() method.

OF COURSE, this is for testing/debugging/diagnosis perspective and NEVER should hit production.